# Narasimha mantra मृत्युमृत्युं translation

Tags: translation-request, narasimha

Transaction request of this Narasimha mantra, especially the highlighted part:
उग्रं वीरं महाविष्णुं ज्वलन्तं सर्वतोमुखम्। नृसिंहं भीषणं भद्रं **मृत्युमृत्युं** नमाम्यहम् ॥

here, I have some text showing Mruty**or**mrutyum. Here it might mean the death for the death.

I have seen online translations for मृत्युमृत्युं showing Death and Deathlessness. Is the section Mrutyu here is pronounced as Amrutyu? If not how the deathlessness comes here?

Comment: It means "you are the one who causes death of death itself" or "you are the destroyer of death personified".See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ghOd7lPtskk) video by ISKCON Bangalore.